# Using relative links in Blogger

Tags: html, hyperlink, web, blogs, blogger

i am using blogger

when i need to mention a link , in a post of my blog and the link is actually a link of my own blog post , i am mentioning itside < a >tag with

www.my_blog_name.blogspot.in/12/2013/how_to_do.html

```
if i changed my blog name then the link will be dead ,
```

So what i want is , i just want mention the link with out my blog name

for example

instead of

```
www.my_blog_name.blogspot.in/12/2013/how_to_do.html
```

i need to mention it like

```
/12/2013/how_to_do.html
```

**so even though if i changed my blog name it will work**

if you guys having anyother solution for changing blog name does't affects links inside my posts plz mention it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blogger has `<$BlogURL$>` tag

`<$BlogURL$>` points to the URL of your blog.

Usage: A good value for a "home" link, or the "back to current" link in an archive template, e.g.

`<a href="<$BlogURL$>">home</a>`

Can also be used as a base href, to make relative links work in both the main page and in archive pages in a separate directory.

So you can do

`<a href="<$BlogURL$>/12/2013/how_to_do.html">Your URL</a>`

---

> Blogger makes relative links (links like `<a
>   href="archives/archive.html">` are relative, links like `<a
>   href="http://www.domain.com/archives/archive.html">` are absolute
>   links) a bit more difficult to manage than usual, because most people
>   keep their archives in a different directory than their main page. If
>   you link to "images/mypic.jpg" in a post, then when that post is
>   archived the link will point to "archives/images/mypic.jpg" and thus
>   not be found. The same thing happens if you put a relative link in
>   your main template, because the archive pages are also created from
>   your main template. Fear not, there are two simple fixes.
>
> Fix one is to use a "base href" tag to tell the browser to start every
>   relative url with the path to your main directory. In your main
>   template, in the `<head>` section, include the tag `<base
>   href="<$BlogURL$>">`. If you have the separate archive index page style
>   of archives, include a base href in the  section of your archive
>   template as well. The next time you publish or post & publish, all
>   your relative links will start from the directory where you have your
>   main page, whether they are in that directory, or in your archives
>   directory. Just be sure you remember to change the Blog URL in your
>   settings if you move your blog!
>
> The second fix is to use server-rooted paths rather than relative
>   paths: a server rooted path starts with a slash, and lists all the
>   directories from the root directory of the server. For example, if
>   your main page was `www.example.com/index.html` and your archives were
>   in `www.example.com/archives/archive.html`, then a server-rooted link to
>   the archives would be `<a href="/archives/archive.html">`, and a
>   server-rooted link to an image in `www.example.com/images/` would look
>   like `<img src="/images/image.jpg">`. However, if your main page is in
>   `www.freehost.com/bunch12/~username/blog/blogger.html`, a server-rooted
>   link will start `/bunch12/~username/blog/`, and using a base href tag
>   will be a whole lot easier (once you get used to it).

[Source](http://archives.blogspot.in/)

Comment: Can this be used in the conditional if statement? E.g.:
`<b:if cond='data:blog.url == &quot;<$BlogURL$>/2016/10/something.html&quot;'>` ? What if when visitors accessing using SSL? Will `<$BlogURL$>` contain `https://` too?