# Blogger home URL retrieved via json

Tags: javascript, json, blogger

*Disclaimer: I have no knowledge of programming.

I'm just doing my best to catch up with as much as possible.*

While reading (and later on trying out) the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924652/using-relative-links-in-blogger), I was thinking that a possibly nice & useful update would be to have the same kind of info in json terms, i.e. how do I retrieve the "home" URL of a Blogger blog by means of json.

I tried to figure it out on my own, since I know, for example, that...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function specialpost(json) {
 document.write('<div>');
// VARIABLE DECLARATION
 var i;
 var j;
// LOOP
 for (i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++)
 {
  for (j = 0; j < json.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
   if (json.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == 'alternate') {
    break;
   }
  }
var postUrl = "'" + json.feed.entry[i].link[j].href + "'";
var postTitle = json.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
var postContent = json.feed.entry[i].content.$t;
var item = '<h3><a href="' + postUrl + '" target="_blank">' + postTitle + '</a></h3><p>' + postContent + '</p>';
 document.write(item);
 }
 document.write('</div>');
 }
</script>
<script src="https://MYBLOG.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/special?max-results=NUMBER_OF_POSTS_DISPLAYED&alt=json-in-script&callback=specialpost"></script>
```

...will give me a `div`, containing title (incl. link) and content of a desired number of posts labeled "special", but I got a bit confused halfway through my attempt.

I'm using [jsonviewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) to view my blog's json code in comprehensible tree-like form, and I'm guessing that if the URL to each post is stored somewhere inside `[] entry`, then the URL to the blog itself is probably stored somewhere inside `[] link`.

**Question**: Am I right?

`[] link` contains 4 entries: `{}0`  `{}1`  `{}2` and `{}3`
each one of them, in turn, containing 3 entries:

- `rel` set to `"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed"`  `"self"`  `"alternate"` and `"hub"` respectively
- `type` set to `"application/atom+xml"` for the first two and `text/html` for the third one
  - not defined for `{}3`
- `href` set to
  `"http://MYBLOG.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default"`
  (*which followed by* `?alt=json` *gives us the URL to the very same json code

  I entered into* [jsonviewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) *in order to get the tree-like view*)
  `"https://www.blogger.com/feed/1234567890123456789/posts/default?alt=json"`
  (*that 19-digit number being, I suppose, some machine-wise generated numeric name

  that Google has assigned to my blog*)
  `"http://MYBLOG.blogspot.com"` and
  `"http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com"`  respectively.

I guess what I'm after is `{}2`

**Question**: Am I right again? If so, how can I declare that the value of, say, `var myblogUrl` is set to the `href` stored inside that `{}2` entry?

**Last, but not least**: What are the other three entries for? The `href` stored in entry `{}0` resembles the one taking you to a kind of subscription page where you can choose by what means you would like to subscribe to the blog in question. Is this really the case?

Answer (score 0):

According to the ATOM specification for `link` element ( Refer to http://atomenabled.org/developers/syndication/#recommendedEntryElements )

> link -    Identifies a related Web page. The type of relation is defined
>   by the rel attribute. An entry is limited to one alternate per type
>   and hreflang. An entry must contain an alternate link if there is no
>   content element. More info [here](http://atomenabled.org/developers/syndication/#link).

Therefore, the URLs inside the `link` entry will keep changing according to the request being made. You will have to use the JavaScript `split` function to the get the value of the homepage  -

```
var myblogUrl = json.feed.link[0].href.split('feeds')[0];
```

**Note:** This will work if you request the feed with the URL of the type - `myblog.blogspot.com`. But if you request feeds from `blogger.com` (like for example - https://www.blogger.com/feeds/596098824972435195/posts/default/-/android?alt=json ) then changes will have to be made to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = json.feed.link.find(function($) {
    return $.rel === "alternate";
}).href.split('/search/')[0];
```